# Get the value from flask html to python

Tags: python, html, flask, infragistics, ignite-ui

Given below the html code I have created flask server using python. Here I'm
taking only checkboxSelectCombo and after selecting the checkboxes in the flask UI, I want to print those values in python as I click on any flask button.
How to get and print that values in the python?
If anyone knows the answer please help me out.

Thank you

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>OPTIMIZATION</title>

       <title></title>
    <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined CSS Files -->
    <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined JavaScript Files -->
    <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1px;
}
</style>


<body  bgcolor="#a9d284">

<img src="/static/images/logo.gif" alt="Related Book 1" width="300" height="80" align="right">
<script src="/static/scripts.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <h1>PORTFOLIO OPTIMIZATION</h1>

    <style>
        .combo-label {margin-bottom:.5em;}
    </style>


<form method="POST" action="">

        <h4 class="combo-label">SELECT THE STOCK OPTIONS</h4>
    <div id="checkboxSelectCombo"></div>

    <br><br>

    <h4>SELECT THE INPUT DATE</h4>
        <input type="date" name="date1" placeholder="Start date">
        <input type="date" name="date2" placeholder="End date">

    <br><br>

<h4>ENTER CONSTRAINTS CRITERIA</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>    </th>
    <th>Cheap</th>
    <th>Moderate</th>
    <th>Expensive</th>
    <th>PUT</th>
    <th>CALL</th>
    <th>Not Recommended</th>
    <th>Highly Liquid</th>
    <th>Moderately Liquid</th>
    <th>Less Liquid</th>
    <th>MPO</th>
    <th>PO</th>
    <th>LPO</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Group_Min</td>
     <td class="td"><input type="text" name="min1"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="min2" /></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="min3"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="min4"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="min5"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="min6"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="min7"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="min8"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="min9"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="min10"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="min11"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="min12"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Group_Max</td>
      <td class="td"><input type="text" name="max1"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="max2"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="max3"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="max4"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="max5"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="max6"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="max7"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="max8"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="max9"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="max10"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="max11"/></td>
        <td class="td"><input type="text" name="max12"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>

    <br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="GET RESULTS">
</form>


    <script>

        var colors = [
            { Name: "FP FP Equity" },
            { Name: "SAN FP Equity" },
            { Name: "NOK1V FH Equity" },
            { Name: "SAN SQ Equity" },
            { Name: "EOA GY Equity" },
            { Name: "SIE GY Equity" },
            { Name: "ENI IM Equity" },
            { Name: "UC IM Equity" },
            { Name: "INGA NA Equity" },
            { Name: "TEF SQ Equity" },
            { Name: "BNP FP Equity" },
            { Name: "BBVA SQ Equity" },
            { Name: "ALV GY Equity" }

        ];

        $(function () {

            $("#singleSelectCombo").igCombo({
                width: 300,
                dataSource: colors,
                textKey: "Name",
                valueKey: "Name",
                dropDownOnFocus: true,
                dropDownOrientation: "bottom"
            });

            $("#multiSelectCombo").igCombo({
                width: 300,
                dataSource: colors,
                textKey: "Name",
                valueKey: "Name",
                multiSelection: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                dropDownOrientation: "bottom"
            });

            $("#checkboxSelectCombo").igCombo({
                width: 300,
                dataSource: colors,
                textKey: "Name",
                valueKey: "Name",
                multiSelection: {
                    enabled: true,
                    showCheckboxes: true
                },
                dropDownOrientation: "bottom"
            });

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>



<!doctype html>
<title>Simple tables</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
<div class=page>
  <h2>OPTIMIZED VALUES</h2>
  {% for table in tables %}
    <h3>{{titles[loop.index]}}</h3>
    {{ table|safe }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Python backend code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from optimization_excel.app import rough_bkend as r1

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/opt')
def index():
    return render_template('rough_portopt.html')


@app.route('/opt', methods=['POST'])
def opt():

    val = request.form.getlist('checkboxSelectCombo')
    print(val)

    res1, res2, res3 = r1.get_res1()
    return render_template('rough_portopt.html', tables=[res1.to_html(), res2.to_html()],
                           titles=['na', 'Test Results', 'Constraint values'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What is a "flask button"? I can't see where Flask features in your code?

Comment: In this code i have not given the button. Here i gave only the main code, in my original one i had given button using input tag with the python back end code.

Comment: In what "original one"? None of the code here has anything to do with Flask. And the HTML button has nothing to do with Flask either. I think you're misunderstanding what Flask is, as a web framework.

Comment: I edited the code section and had given the complete code.@roganjosh

Comment: Apologies for sounding pedantic but I don't think you have. You still haven't included any Flask code (that small bit at the end relies on Jinja2). What you're asking requires us to build the backend and then create the required forms to communicate with it. Unless I'm missing something, this is not trivial work you're asking for.

Comment: Sorry, I added the python backend code now. And the get_res1() function in that is another part for my calculation, i want only the selected checkboxes to be printed in python after clicking get_result button. If you can please have a look and answer me.

Answer (score 0):

So I place `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right before your `print(val)` code and found

```
-> print(val)
(Pdb) p request.form
ImmutableMultiDict([('date1', ''), ('date2', ''), ('min1', ''), ('min2', ''),
('min3', ''), ('min4', ''), ('min5', ''), ('min6', ''), ('min7', ''), ('min8', ''),
('min9', ''), ('min10', ''), ('min11', ''), ('min12', ''), ('max1', ''), ('max2', ''),
('max3', ''), ('max4', ''), ('max5', ''),('max6', ''), ('max7', ''), ('max8', ''),
('max9', ''), ('max10', ''), ('max11', ''), ('max12', '')])
```

So we see checkboxSelectCombo is not part of the form.  Right-clicking on the drop box and select Inspect, I examine the generated HTML and find

```
<input type="hidden" class="ui-igcombo-hidden-field" value="SAN FP Equity">
```

Ah, this element doesn't have a name.  Your problem seems to be in your javascript, not flask.

Comment: I work in python, I dont know anything about javascript, so then is that checkboxSelectCombo a javascript code? Can't I get the selected values in that to python? Do i need to change the code for checkbox selections? @Frustrated

Comment: I don't do much javascript and none with igCombo which is creating the comboBox input item.  Bottom line, unless it creates an input item with a name attribute `<input name="somename" />`, the POST request will not send it.  Check the vendor documentation and examples on how to specify the name attribute.  This isn't a Python or Flask problem.

Comment: Just provide a name to the combo through the option exposed: https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2018.2/ui.igcombo#options:inputName